# 2 in every 3 requests to IIS website get error 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I migrated a site from server 2003 to server 2012. now something really weird is happening on the IIS site.

The site is built on Webforms, and aspx pages.

Every 2 in 3 requests are i get error 404, and 1 in 3 go work fine. Get this screen on failure.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the IIS logs and post an extract here. Is it certain paths that are not working or is it the same path that sometimes works, sometimes doesn't?

Comment: There is a lot you're not telling us. You could have any kind of set-up with HTTP handlers and other rules in the HTTP request pipeline. We need waaaaaay more information.

Comment: Hi @IanMercer my logs dont seem to update when i call pages. there is some earlier logs from in the day

Comment: Hi @Dai I havent setup any HTTP handlers or others rules in HTTP request pipeline.